# Having problems deploying a JSP application in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, spring, jsp, tomcat, log4j

I am having problems deploying a dynamic web application in Eclipse.  My application is made up of JSPs, uses Spring/Hibernate frameworks, and has a MySQL database backend.  When I deploy the application, I get the error:

```
HTTP Status 404 - 

type Status report

message 

description The requested resource () is not available.

Apache Tomcat/6.0.29
```

In the console, I am getting the following statements when I clean the project:

> log4j:ERROR LogMananger.repositorySelector was null likely due to
>   error in class reloading, using NOPLoggerRepository. log4j:WARN No
>   appenders could be found for logger
>   (org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet). log4j:WARN Please
>   initialize the log4j system properly.
>
> When I deploy the project, I get the following error in the console:
>
> log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger
>   (org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet). log4j:WARN Please
>   initialize the log4j system properly.

I am not sure why I am getting the above statements, as I have my log4j.xml file in the root project folder of my web application in Eclipse.  If this is not the correct location, then where should it be?

I am using the latest version of Eclipse (Helios), and I'm using Tomcat6 as my web server. Can anyone see what the problem is?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how are you deploying your application ?

Comment: Thanks very much for your comment.  I've gone into detail under Luis' answer below.  Please free to ask any follow up questions.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be that your application is not deployed.
Can you open the index page of your application?
How are you making the deployment?

Luis

Comment: Thanks very much for your prompt replies.  I am deploying it by including the relevant subprojects in the build path, as well as the necessary jar files.  I've also included the subprojects via the deployment assembly.  I try to deploy the application by right-clicking on the web project, and selecting "run on server".  I try this with the server stopped, or has already started.  I am unable to open up the home page.  My web application includes several sub projects, is composed of the Spring, and Hibernate frameworks, and a MySQL database backend.  Let me know if you need additional info.

Comment: later i will elaborate more. At your position I would try to make a trivial "hallo world" example in order to see if the deployment took place or not.

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  I did create a very simple "hello world" dynamic web application, and was able to deploy it on tomcat.  It is merely composed of one web page that says "hello world".  Because I am only using tomcat for deploying my web applications, I am getting the following output:

Comment: Nov 27, 2010 9:10:52 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin;.;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Program Files/Java/jre6/bin/client;C:/Program Files/Java/jre6/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre6/lib/i386;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\bin;

Comment: Nov 27, 2010 9:10:54 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init

INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080

Nov 27, 2010 9:10:54 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load

INFO: Initialization processed in 5134 ms

Nov 27, 2010 9:10:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start

INFO: Starting service Catalina

Nov 27, 2010 9:10:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start

INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.29

Nov 27, 2010 9:10:56 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor HadithSearcherWeb.xml

Comment: log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet).

log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.

Nov 27, 2010 9:11:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log

INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'hadithSearcher'

Comment: Hibernate: select indexconfi0_.n_index_config_id as n1_7_, indexconfi0_.vch_base_index_location as vch2_7_, indexconfi0_.d_last_build_date as d3_7_, indexconfi0_.vch_live_index_location as vch4_7_, indexconfi0_.vch_temp_index_location as vch5_7_ from sc_index_config indexconfi0_

Comment: Nov 27, 2010 9:11:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor

INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor testApp.xml

Nov 27, 2010 9:11:09 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start

INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080

Nov 27, 2010 9:11:10 PM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init

INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009

Nov 27, 2010 9:11:10 PM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start

INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/63 config=null

Nov 27, 2010 9:11:10 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start

INFO: Server startup in 15351 ms

Comment: I hope this helps.  I really don't know where I am going wrong.  Thanks again for your time and patience.